# ModelChoiceField shows objects instead on contents

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

How can I change my code to show contents instead of objects ?

forms.py:

```
unit_set = AnalysisVariableUnit.objects.all()
for unit in AnalysisVariableUnit.objects.all():
    print(unit.__dict__)

class AnalyysimuuttujaForm(forms.Form):
    technical_name = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(
                                        attrs={
                                            'class':'readonly_able tn'
                                            }
                                        ))
    decimals = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_DS)
    decimals_format = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_DS)
    units = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=False,
            widget=forms.Select,
            queryset=unit_set,
        )
```

this outputs:

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f2038ea51d0>, 'id': 1, 'contents': 'indeksipisteluku'}
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f2038ea5240>, 'id': 2, 'contents': '%'}
```

I want to have 'indeksipisteluku' and '%' as selectables in my drop down, which now shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AnalysisVariableUnit object (...)` is the default output of Django's `__str__` for a model.

Add a descriptive `__str__` to your model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the **str**() function in model class to customize the dropdown correctly.

```
class AnalysisVariableUnit(models.Model):
    # your data variables
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.contents # or any thing you want to show in dropdown
```

Comment: Great thanks Vinay Vishwakarma, it worked indeed, even better than I was expecting !